# add div text to array

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add this `<div><a href="">Test</a>and another <a href="">Test</a></div>` text to array like this: `['Test', 'and another', 'Test']`, but the result is `['Test', 'Test']`, 'and another' text is ignored.

```
let text = [];
$('div').children().each(function () {
  text.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This is because there are only 2 children of div if you want 'and another' in array use <p> tag like <p>and another</p>

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH You are slightly mistaken. There are 3 direct children of div, 2 anchor tags and one text node. To select text node fortunately we have special functions like `contents()` in jQuery and other options in javascript. But if we wanted to select it for pure CSS based styling, there would be no option but to wrap it between `<p>`, `<span>` or other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.contents()** instead of **.children()**. **children()** function does not include comments and text node. So your function would be:

```
let text = [];
$('div').contents().each(function () {
  text.push($(this).text());
});
```

[Ref Link](http://%20https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxmowz3e/)

Comment: You saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

as it is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp)

.children() only return html elements and not texts so it is obvious that **and another** is not included in the items. in order to achieve your desired result you can simply put it in `<span>` tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just pure Javascript, no need Jquery.

Using [.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) and [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
var text = [];

document.querySelector('div').childNodes.forEach((el) => {
  text.push(el.textContent)
})

console.log(text)
```

```html
<div><a href="">Test</a>and another <a href="">Test</a></div>
```